# Link of React Router, update redux state before redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `Link` component from React Router that looks like:

```
<Link
    className={mainClass}
    to={to}
    target={target}
>
    Link
</Link>
```

I need to update redux store (or run any method before redirect), since I need to send a value from the Link page to the destination page and the route cannot be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of using React-Router `Link` component try to dispatch an action updating your store and when action is finished redirect to given URl manually using `browserHistory`

Answer (score 2):

You can update the Redux store in [`onEnter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) hook.

You may want to pass the third argument `callback` to block transitions until it is called.

Comment: there is a callback in Link component?

Comment: No, the `onEnter` hook has `callback` as the third argument. Please check the documentation [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback). You can wrap your route definitions inside function with `store` argument available and use that value to update Redux.

Comment: but, I have the info before redirect, they question is how to call the dispatch, if the redirect is done before.

Comment: The `onEnter` hook is called before the redirect happens. The redirect is delayed until you call the `callback`. Update the Redux in the hook and when it's done, call the `callback` to go to the target page.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/ming-soon/mern-starter/blob/master/app/routes/index.js#L46) to see how to pass `store` and use `onEnter` hook. It is not a perfect example, but you can get a gist from it.

Comment: hmm, but I dont think I would have the prev component data there

Comment: Then as @bartek said, you can dispatch an asynchronous action to update Redux and after the promise is resolved, manually redirect to the target page with `browserHistory`.